# How to use a web component in a solid.js project?

Tags: reactjs, solid-js

[image: Property 'aero-modal' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.]

When I try to use a web component in my Solid.js project (instead of building one), it doesn't recognize the tag as it is not an intrinsic element. How can I setup solid.js to recognize web components?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how you can extend the global types, to get rid of TS error:

```
import type { ComponentProps } from "solid-js"

declare module "solid-js" {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      "aero-modal": ComponentProps<"div"> & { foo: number }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know how to get the custom elements themselves to work though... But I would assume they already do. They are custom elements after all, and solid doesn't judge. If the tag in JSX is in lowercase, it should treat it as an html element.

Note: The `ComponentProps<"div"> & { foo: number }` I've put there, are the props. You could put an `{}` there if the component doesn't have any.

Answer (score 2):

If you're extending `HTMLElement`, a more general solution may be

```
declare module 'solid-js' {
  namespace JSX {
    type ElementProps<T> = {
      // Add both the element's prefixed properties and the attributes
      [K in keyof T]: Props<T[K]> & HTMLAttributes<T[K]>;
    }
    // Prefixes all properties with `prop:` to match Solid's property setting syntax
    type Props<T> = {
      [K in keyof T as `prop:${string & K}`]?: T[K];
    }
    interface IntrinsicElements extends ElementProps<HTMLElementTagNameMap> {
    }
  }
}
```

From [an issue on the Solid github](https://github.com/solidjs/solid/issues/616#issuecomment-1144074821).